# Redirecting to a new url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anybody provide an example on if on a certain page redirect to new page

For example.

If on `www.site.com/womens/shoes/all.aspx` then they get redirected to `www.site.com/womens/shoes/sale/all.aspx`

Would i use something like this code below?

```
window.location.replace('www.site.com/womens/shoes/sale/all.aspx');
```

Need this to work also when the link "Women Shoes" (id=#cli68) is clicked (normally it would go to first url but want to goto the second url when clicked and when on the first link page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery with the `$document.ready()` function

Add support for jquery and add this to your javascript code

```
//executed when doc is ready
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (document.URL=='www.site.com/womens/shoes/all.aspx'){//checks current url location
        window.location.replace("www.site.com/womens/shoes/sale/all.aspx");//redirect it
    }  
});
```

If you struggle to add javascript to your aspx code you can use the following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx

Here is a working example

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "document loaded" );
        if (document.URL!='http://shop.mischiefshoes.co.nz/estore/category/women%27s/christmas%20styles.aspx'){//checks current url location
            console.log( "redirect" );
            window.location.replace("http://shop.mischiefshoes.co.nz/estore/stylelist/all.aspx?page=1&rsb=%2C0%7C3%7C14%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C48%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C68%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C77%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C78%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C90%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C92%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C102%7CDark%20Red%2C0%7C3%7C108%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C113%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C120%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C127%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C129%7CBlack%2C0%7C3%7C140%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C144%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C164%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C174%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C177%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C181%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C191%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C212%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C224%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C225%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C246%7CRed%20Multi%2C0%7C3%7C261%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C266%7CRed%20Multi%2C0%7C3%7C267%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C280%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C293%7CWhite%20Multi%2C0%7C3%7C301%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C303%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C328%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C350%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C362%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C417%7CNavy%20Red%20White%2C0%7C3%7C427%7CRed%20White%20Navy%2C0%7C3%7C440%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C481%7CFuschia%2C0%7C3%7C517%7CPurple%2C0%7C3%7C518%7CBlack%2C0%7C3%7C539%7CBlack%20White%2C0%7C3%7C544%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C559%7CPewter%2C0%7C3%7C606%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C627%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C634%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C638%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C641%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C650%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C660%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C668%7CFuschia%2C0%7C3%7C671%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C695%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C704%7Cred%2C0%7C3%7C719%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C727%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C741%7CNavy%20Yellow%20Red%2C0%7C3%7C765%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C779%7CRed%20Suede%2C0%7C3%7C847%7CFluro%20Red%2C0%7C3%7C860%7CRed%20Sqiggle%2C0%7C3%7C870%7CNavy%2FRed%2C0%7C3%7C877%7CRed%20Squiggle%2C0%7C3%7C880%7CRed%20Squig%2C0%7C3%7C909%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C924%7CRed%2FFuschia%2C0%7C3%7C934%7CTan%2FRed%2C0%7C3%7C972%7Cred%2C0%7C3%7C997%7CRed%20Pony%2C0%7C3%7C1001%7CRed%2FEggplant%2C0%7C3%7C1008%7CRed%2FSlate%2C0%7C3%7C1058%7CWhite%2FRed%2FGrey%2C0%7C3%7C1068%7CRed%2FBeige%20%2C0%7C3%7C1151%7CRed%20Tartan%2C0%7C3%7C1237%7Cnavy%2Fred%2Fwhite%2C0%7C3%7C1263%7CRed%2C0%7C3%7C1277%7CWht%2Fblk%2Fred%2C0%7C3%7C1282%7Cred%2C0%7C3%7C1303%7CRed%20Snake%2C0%7C3%7C1308%7Cred&rsc=%2C0%2C");//redirect it
        }         
    });

    $( window ).load(function() {
        console.log( "window loaded" );
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    The content of the document......
</body>
</html>
```

I used `document.URL!=` because the url of the page is different so to test this code you need to copy this into an emmpty html doc.
If you want to integrate it into your code use `document.URL==`

Hope that helps,

Comment: do you know if this will work if there are %characters in the new url? 

Eg:

$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (document.URL=='www.site.com/women's/christmas styles.aspx'){//checks current url location
        window.location.replace("www.site.comwomen's/christmas styles.aspx?page=1&rsb=%2C0%7C3%7C14%7CRed%2C");//redirect it
    }  
});

Comment: I think it is ok as it is only a string. Did you try it? if you have an url I can test I can give it a go

Comment: http://assiste.com.free.fr/p/faq_webmaster/HTML_ASCII_Escape_codes_H2_%20!$%25&%27%28%29+,-..html works for the redirection

Comment: These are the url i want to redirect from and to.

http://jsfiddle.net/jc0807/bpcz1zpL/

Comment: @Jc0807 use encodeURI() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: Also, if you want to simulate an HTTP redirect use `window.location.replace`. Otherwise, just use `window.location.href` for the effect of clicking a link!

Comment: @Gabriel the script is causing an infinite loop, also the "IF" clause is allowing any category page link to be redirected instead of just that one page.

Comment: as I said, if you blindly copy paste the file in an empty docunent called example.html for example it will work ok. Otherwise if you use it in the original document (with its  adress) then chage the if condition.

Comment: @Gabriel thank you for clearing that up, any chance you could help provide a working example without it looping

Comment: Take the example I give you and copy paste it into an enpty file: JC027.html and open it. This DOES NOT LOOP in IE and Chrome. Could you confirm?

Comment: @Gabriel i copied the code into notepad++ and opened, nothing changed. The issue is i need to only copy the script into a already existing template. It loops in firefox when i insert this script. Thanks

Comment: tested this exact code in Firefox and it does not loop. post your template and I will take a look

Comment: @Gabriel the template is a ecommerce platform usually we just allowed to add html, css, javascript using a "html widget" like box. But shouldn't it just be the <script> part that i need an not the html elements?

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a onclick event for the link and then use

```
window.location = "www.site.com/womens/shoes/sale/all.aspx";
```

another option would be to run a function on page load that would just change the href on links you wanted to the new sale links. I think this option is better because everything acts the way the user expects.